# "When I said....I meant to say...", is this idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In a conversation with a friend I wrote a sentence which I later realized had a mistake, so I said:

> When I said....I meant to say...

which struck me as unnatural.

Is this construction idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty natural. It's sort of shorthand for (the slightly more natural):

- When I said ... what I really meant to say was ...